# SQL Pivot not grouping correctly

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
select event_date
,ga_session_id
,organic
,none
from (
select sd.projectsite,sd.ga_session_id
,sd.traffic_source_medium,sd.traffic_source_source,sd.event_date
,case when traffic_source_medium='(none)' then 'none' else  traffic_source_medium end as 
traffic_source_medium_2
--,ep.event_name
--,ep.eventparams_key
,sd.geo_country,sd.geo_region,sd.geo_city
--,count(*) as session_count
from google_analytics.ga_sessiondetails_distinct sd where  sd.ga_session_id in 
('1678364512' ,'1677708135')
--group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
) as src 
pivot 
( count(traffic_source_medium_2)
for traffic_source_medium_2 in ('organic','none')) as Pvt
```

I am trying to bring in just 2 rows (1 for for each session id). Session id '1677708135' has only organic sessions where as session id '1678364512' has organic and none sessions. So it is showing 2 rows instead of one and in total 3 rows for both session ids. how do I fix this

[image: please link here to view the image]

[Sample input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTXuC.png)

Comment: Show us what the expected result should be. Do you want 4 rows? i.e. don't focus on what is wrong - instead focus on what you want. & Please don't use images, just a simple text table will be more than sufficient.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell -No I want just 2 rows.. 1 for each session id.. for session id '1678364512' I would like to see organic and none data in the same row

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve only one row per session is to use `group by` and instead of using the "pivot" feaure, achieve the conversion of rows to columns using "conditional aggregates" (which are simply case expressions inside an aggregate function like `count`. e.g.

```
SELECT
      ga_session_id
    , MAX(event_date) AS event_date
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN traffic_source_medium = 'organic' THEN 1 END) AS organic
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN traffic_source_medium = '(none)' THEN 1 END) AS none
FROM google_analytics.ga_sessiondetails_distinct sd
WHERE sd.ga_session_id IN ('1678364512', '1677708135')
GROUP BY ga_session_id;
```

Note `count` ignores NULL that's why there is no `else 0` or you could be more explicit and include `else NULL`. Another variant is to use `sum` like the following - although I do prefer counting when that is the functional purpose of the query:

```
SELECT
      ga_session_id
    , MAX(event_date) AS event_date
    , SUM(CASE WHEN traffic_source_medium = 'organic' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS organic
    , SUM(CASE WHEN traffic_source_medium = '(none)' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS none
FROM google_analytics.ga_sessiondetails_distinct sd
WHERE sd.ga_session_id IN ('1678364512', '1677708135')
GROUP BY ga_session_id;
```

Comment: The above query does not work

Comment: There is a completely new quey now that you clarified you only wanted one row per session.